# Oracle SQL to exclude outliers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sample data as below and I wanted to identify and mark outliers. The logic i was thinking is group by dept_id into quartiles and mark anything greater than 2nd quartile (median excluding outlier values) + 20% standard deviation as an outlier.. Not sure how to EXCLUDE OUTLIER values from the Median in a SQL construct.

```
dept_id Sal
10     250
10     290
10     320
10     100000
10     500000
20     800
20     860
20     700
20     850000
20     1000000
```

Output we would desire

```
  dept_id   Sal  Outlier
    10     250      N
    10     290      N
    10     320      N
    10     100000   Y 
    10     500000   Y
    20     800      N
    20     860      N
    20     700      N  
    20     850000   Y
    20     1000000  Y
```

Comment: Can you please detail the computation rule for *2nd quartile + 20% standard deviation*?

Comment: I was thinking to use NTILE(3) OVER( PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY sal asc ) as qrtle, but not working

Answer (score 0):

> The logic i was thinking is group by dept_id into quartiles and mark anything greater than 2nd quartile (median excluding outlier values) + 20% standard deviation as an outlier..

Strange definition of outlier.  The second quartile would be the *median*, which seems odd to mix in with the standard deviation (which is usually based on the average).  And 0.2 standard deviation would never be considered a very wide range in statistics.

But that is your definition.  You can do:

```
select t.*,
       (case when salary >= median(salary) over (partition by dept_id) - 0.2 * stddev(salary) over (partition by dept_id)  and
                  salary <= median(salary) over (partition by dept_id) + 0.2 * stddev(salary) over (partition by dept_id)
             then 'N' else 'Y'
        end) as outlier  
from t
```

Comment: Thank you, but when we take median(salary) we r taking into account the outlier sal values as well.. the above query is marking incorrect outliers

Comment: @stackuser . . . This answer the question that you specifically asked.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with more clarity if you want a better method for identifying outliers.